# PHP Ckeditor just load old data?

Tags: php, ckeditor

I have a problem with ckeditor. After submit new data, when return edit data, ckeditor show the old data. I must refresh, it load new data ?

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'my_content', {
                entities_latin: false,
                entities_greek: false,
                toolbar: 'Full'
            });
```

Comment: what you do yet

Comment: may be you are showing data before updating it.

Comment: @MdHasiburRahaman i have recent update code in my question

Comment: @RahulVyas  it does not working

Comment: stop ckditor and check is there new in textbox or old data
i think this problem not for ckeditor,.

Comment: thanks all! i found the reason was cache data that i set before in .htaccess file